# Run Parallel Execution on Selenum Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
  <test thread-count="1" name="Transactoin">
  <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5555/wd/hub"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="POM_Test.ATransactionTest"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test thread-count="1" name="MyAlerts">
  <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:5556/wd/hub"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="POM_Test.MyAlertsTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

`ATransactionTest` `Class` has `47` Test cases
`MyAlertsTest` `Class` has `40` Test cases.

I wanted to `run both classes simulatneously` and MyAlertsTest should take remoteurl which is given in the parameter and ATransaction test should take remoteurl given the parameter.

But what happens is, `ATransactionTest` runs first in `Node1` once all test case completed `MyAlerts` runs in `Node2`. How to run simulatenously.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the document, TestNG will respect the order of tests in your xml file.

Now, you want to run both classes in parallel so you have set `parallel="classes"` which is correct. However, your tests will still run on a single thread, meaning if you have **multiple classes** in your test group then it 'll run them in parallel but all tests will run in series one after another.

To solve this issue, you can either add multiple classes under same test group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
  <test thread-count="2" name="Transactoin">
  <parameter name="parameterName" value="parameterValue"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="Class1"/>
      <class name="Class2"/>
     </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Or as in **your case you can set parallel option to tests**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
  <test thread-count="1" name="Transactoin">
  <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5555/wd/hub"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="POM_Test.ATransactionTest"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test thread-count="1" name="MyAlerts">
  <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:5556/wd/hub"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="POM_Test.MyAlertsTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: I have tried parallel = tests. Browsers opens in the different nodes. but commands are going to only one node which opens the browser latest. Eg., i wanted to enter the username field.. In the same node it enters twice..

Comment: that was due to driver issue.. I have fixed.. thanks for the answer